# how to send id parameter in url and get the id parameter on the other page with react js?

Tags: reactjs

this is what I am doing the product.vendor_id is my id I am new to react js please help

```html
<a href="#/base/property/"+{product.vendor_id}><Button block color="secondary" className="btn-pill">0</Button></a>
```

Comment: <a href={\`#/base/property/${product.vendor_id}\`}>

Comment: hello jamie thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `template literals` or put the string concatenation within `{}`

```
<a href=`#/base/property/${product.vendor_id}`><Button block color="secondary" className="btn-pill">0</Button></a>
```

or

```
<a href={"#/base/property/"+product.vendor_id}><Button block color="secondary" className="btn-pill">0</Button></a>
```

In case you are using react-router, you would make use of `Link` from `react-router-dom` like

```
<Link to=`/base/property/${product.vendor_id}`><Button block color="secondary" className="btn-pill">0</Button></Link>
```

and in the component which is rendered on `/base/property/:vendorId`, you can make access the vendor id like `this.props.match.params.vendorId`

Comment: Thank you Shubham but i have one more question like i am a php(codeigniter) developer i am noobie to react js i need to know how to get this id on other page i need to post thi id to the api please help :)

Comment: Are you using React-router in your App?

Comment: No i am not using it.

Comment: If you aren't using react-router, you need to parse the url and get vendorId from it. I however will recommend that you use react-router

Comment: Hello Shubham this.props.match.params.vendorId is giving me undefined i am using const Id = this.props.match.params.vendor_id; console.log(Id);